# "System.OutOfMemoryException" в System.Drawing.dll

Tags: c#, bitmap

Собственно, уменьшаю и обрезаю изображения до 200*300 в цикле и выдает ошибку "System.OutOfMemoryException" в System.Drawing.dll Если цикл убрать то все хорошо работает. img_files массив выбранных фото. В каком направлении копать?

```
if (img_files != null)
        {
            int nWidth, nHeight;
            Image img;
            for (photo_num = 0; photo_num < img_files.Length; photo_num++)
            {

                img = Image.FromFile(img_files[photo_num]);
                if (img.Width / img.Height >= 1.5)
                {
                    nHeight = 200;
                    nWidth = 200 * img.Width / img.Height;
                }
                else
                {
                    nWidth = 300;
                    nHeight = 300 * img.Height / img.Width;
                }
                Bitmap img1 = new Bitmap(img, nWidth, nHeight);
                img1 = img1.Clone(new Rectangle(0, 0, 300, 200), img1.PixelFormat); // тут выдает ошибку
                img1.Save("d:\\pyt\\k\\filu", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                img1.Dispose();
                img.Dispose();



            }
        }
```

Comment: Не диспозится самый первый `img1`, который создаётся вызовом `new Bitmap`. Полагаю, можно ввести дополнительную переменную `img2`. Потом диспозить все три.

Comment: Я так понимаю это и предложил Igor, но не помогло

Comment: На каком по счёту изображении вылетает исключение? Каков изначальный размер фоток?

Comment: Действительно, с этим и проблема. Ширину выдает 199,997 естественно округляется до 199, и компилятор выдает верную ошибку.  Сам код был верный, как я понимаю. Причина в округлении переменных

Comment: А Без цикла работало, потому что использовал другую фотку.

Answer (score 2):

Потеряна первая ссылка `img1`.

```
using(Bitmap img1 = new Bitmap(img, nWidth, nHeight))
{
  using (Bitmap img2 = img1.Clone(new Rectangle(0, 0, 300, 200), img1.PixelFormat))
  {
     img2.Save("d:\\pyt\\k\\filu", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
  }
}
```

PS: Выбирайте для переменных осмысленные имена.

Comment: Спасибо) Думал если переменная используется только в маленьком кусочке, то какая разница?

Comment: Не помогло, выдает ту же ошибку на том же месте (на img2) (( Ребят, помогите, не знаю с чем связано((((

Answer (score 0):

Беда в строчке (img.Width / img.Height >= 1.5) Компилятор округлит результат деления до целого значения 1. Условия будет выполнятся не верно и фотография сожмется по неправильному алгоритму. Далее когда фото будет обрезаться не получится построить Rectangle(0, 0, 300, 200) и вылетает ошибка

Comment: (img.Width >= 1.5 * img.Height)

Comment: Вариант) Но я просто назначил img.Width  и img.Height на переменные float